# Class variable wont change

Tags: java

My code looks like this:

```
public class Boxes {

    float length = 0;
    float width = 0;
    float height = 0;

    float fmax = (this.getVol() / 40000);
    int max = (int) fmax;

    String[] items = new String[max];

    public float getVol() {

        return length*width*height;

    }

}
```

The variable 'fmax' wont change when I have an instance of this class and I have set the variables 'length', 'width' and 'height' to values other than zero. Instead I noticed it used the values assigned in the class by default, which are all 0.

Comment: `fmax` won't automatically change just because variables that decided its value originally changed. That's not how variables work. You need to manually reassign `fmax` when you want it to have a new value; or make it a function.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to print fmax?!? if so it will be initialized with the initial values, as you see you initialize it invoking the method

Comment: One option is to add a getFmax() method which will calculate the value everytime and call this getter method instead on accessing the variable directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `Boxes` you make this:

```
Boxes boxes = new Boxes();
```

At this point the state of `boxes` is

> length = 0; width = 0; height = 0; fmax = (0 / 40000);

since length, width and height are initialized with 0, then `getVol() = 0`. So `fmax=0` at the start.

Now let's suppose you change these values:

```
boxes.length = 1;
boxes.height = 1;
boxes.width = 1;
```

This action doesn't change `boxes.fmax`, because it was initializaed with 0 and it doesn't call `getVol` again. If you want to change it, you can use a function `getFmax()` instead.

```
float getFmax() {
    return this.getVol() / 40000;
}
```

this function will return a different value calling `getVol()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is assigned to a math operation, it will be only calculated once. If you want it to change when you change one of the numbers in the math operation, you will need to re-assign it. Instead of using a variable, try using this function which will re-calculate the fmax value every time you want it.

```java
public float getFmax() {
    return this.getVol() / 40000;
}
```